# Cython direct access to Global Variable

Tags: python, variables, global, cython

How can I access a global variable declared with Cython, without using a accessor function?

I tried with following example:

**pyfunktionen_a.pyx**

```
import numpy as np

cdef extern from "funktionen_a.h":
    cdef void setValue(int value_to_set)
    cdef int readValue()
    cdef int value

def pysetValue (_value):
    setValue(_value)

def pyreadValue():
    print readValue()

def manipulateValue(value_to_set):
    value = value_to_set
```

**funktionen_a.c**

```
#include "funktionen_a.h"


void setValue(int value_to_set){

    value = value_to_set;
}

int readValue(){
    return value;
}
```

**funktionen_a.h**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void setValue(int value_to_set);
int readValue();

int value;
```

And with this function I control the whole thing:

**control.py**

```
import pyfunktionen_a

pyfunktionen_a.pysetValue(8)
pyfunktionen_a.pyreadValue()

pyfunktionen_a.manipulateValue(5)
pyfunktionen_a.pyreadValue()
```

What results i **expected**:

```
>>    8
>>    5
```

But what results i **get**:

```
>>    8
>>    8
```

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar enough with cython to know if this is true here as well, but with regular python what you want to do wouldn't work either. Remember that the ``=`` operator operates on *references*, not *values*. When you import a global from another .py, you're essentially doing ``local_name = global_name``. They now both point to the same object in memory. But in the case of an immutable like ``int``, the only way to alter its value is via assignment, and as soon as you do so you're replacing the reference to the other module's instance with a reference to a locally created instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using:

```
def manipulateValue(value_to_set):
    global value
    value = value_to_set
```

Otherwise value will be a local variable in this function.

This link could be useful: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#id34

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right i forget the global keyword.